# PHP echo result from MySQL SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP (testing):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","php","","A");

  $query = "SELECT passport FROM users WHERE mail = '$_POST[mail]';";

  $result = $link->query($query);

}
?>
```

A manual SELECT using the same `$query` shows:

```
mysql> SELECT passport FROM users WHERE mail = 'WhoMe@domain.com';
+----------------------+
| passport             |
+----------------------+
| 8KQSWCZPJAUV1M9D4TFG |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am trying to echo the `$result` in PHP which should show `8KQSWCZPJAUV1M9D4TFG` but it is null. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","php","","A");

  $query = "SELECT passport FROM users WHERE mail = '$_POST[mail]';";

  $result = mysqli_query($query);

  $row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  echo $row["passport"];

}
?>
```

This also is still null.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: you can remove ; from the end of query string if you want, and on the next line echo $query, to make sure what query exactly is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Comment: And output it `echo $row["passport"];`

Comment: Thanks! I gave that a go and updated this question with what I'm using, but it's still not giving me the result that the manual SELECT does?

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "php", "", "A");

$query = "SELECT passport FROM users WHERE mail = '$_POST[mail]';";
$result = $link->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
  echo $row['passport'];
}
```

You need to use object based `MySQLi` in order to use `$link->query()`

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.

It should work for you.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass123', 'test');
$query = "SELECT passport FROM users WHERE mail = '$_POST[mail]'";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

// PRINT
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo stripslashes($row['passport']);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fecth in loop and fix query(remove ;) like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","php","","A");

  $query = "SELECT passport FROM users WHERE mail = '$_POST[mail]'";

  $result = mysqli_query($query);

  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

     echo $row["passport"];
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: @user2656114 : did you try this?